# Lodash function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have array of object:

```
var arr = [{id:1, name:Michael},
    {Id:2, name:"Mix"},
    {Id:3, name:"Mark"},
    {Id:4, name:"Marta"},
    {Id:5, name:"Anna"}];

var desiredId = 3;
```

I try to get object from object array with help of `lodash` library  like that:

```
var result = _.find(arr, 'Id', desiredId);
```

But I always get object with `id = 1`(i.e `{id:1, name:Michael}`).

Any idea why I don't get the expected object (where Id = 3).

Comment: Depending on the version of lodash you're using the third parameter can have different effects on the execution of `_.find`. Check the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs) for the actual behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) lodash documentation, there should be an example where you can use a [matches()](https://lodash.com/docs#matches) shorthand. You will notice that this shorthand is a common occurence when querying from collections.

Example:

```js
var arr = [
    {Id:1, name:"Michael"},
    {Id:2, name:"Mix"},
    {Id:3, name:"Mark"},
    {Id:4, name:"Marta"},
    {Id:5, name:"Anna"}
];

var desiredId = 3;
var result = _.find(arr, { Id: desiredId });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```